# CodeIgniter Enabling Query Strings

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-string

I got this URL:

```
http://twitternieuws.com/class/function/ID?oauth_token=xxxxx&oauth_verifier=xxxxx
```

And I keep getting errors like "The page you requested was not found" or "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters". I tried changing the following options with different settings:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'];
$config['enable_query_strings'];
$config['uri_protocol'];
```

Is there anything I can do to make it work? I am using codeigniter `1.7.2`

Comment: `permitted_uri_chars` is the way to go in this I think. Try putting parts of the url in little by little to see what it's complaining about

Comment: It is the & and the =! When using the & or the = in the URL it doesnot work and gives me the error "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters". But if I set     permitted_uri_chars then I get the error "The page you requested was not found"

Comment: you can't use search-engine friendly segment based URLs and standard query string based URLs simultaneously

Comment: @mahadeb: Do you have a reference? Makes no sense to me what you're saying, in fact I'm doing it right now.

Comment: I use $_GET extensively for purposes that have nothing to do with SEO, on pages that aren't even indexed, Any argument wholly against the use of query strings on the basis of anything related to SEO is unfounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query strings in 1.7.2 are a joke, it uses `?c=controller&m=method` to basically change your pretty urls to psuedo $_GET params. I really can't see why anyone would use it the way it's intended, it's very misleading and is **not** the same as normal query strings.

I *highly* suggest you check out the latest version of Codeigniter, where they do not unset the $_GET array (normal query strings are now usable). In one of the core files in the older versions it says `CI does not use $_GET so we are going to unset() the global $_GET array`. Well, what if **I** need to use $GET? I always thought it was crazy, and people have been screaming for true $_GET support for forever.

Seriously though, it's time to upgrade:

Latest: https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/

Stable: http://codeigniter.com/

Comment: I was afraid of that! I am testing to upgrade to 2.0.2!

Comment: @iSenne: Make sure to read the change log and upgrade instructions, there are a few important (but easy) changes you'll need to make to your existing app. Most importantly, all core classes including Model and Controller are now prefixed with `CI_`

Comment: I was scared to upgrade, almost everything worked without problem though

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading to CodeIgniter 2 is not an option, you can recreate the $_GET variable like so (add this to every controller where you need the query string):

> parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);

And change this in your config.php file:

> // $config['uri_protocol']    = "AUTO"; // change from this
>
> $config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO"; // to this