# how to retrieve HTTP $_GET values with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm stuck with using $_GET variables with CodeIgniter, anyone can help me please?

Comment: @diani-chandra-pertiwi Please check an answer if it is correct and acceptable answer of your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$this->input->get()` or `$this->input->get_post()`

Answer (score 12):

> CodeIgniter comes with three helper
>   functions that let you fetch POST,
>   COOKIE or SERVER items. The main
>   advantage of using the provided
>   functions rather than fetching an item
>   directly ($_POST['something']) is that
>   the functions will check to see if the
>   item is set and return false (boolean)
>   if not. This lets you conveniently use
>   data without having to test whether an
>   item exists first. In other words,
>   normally you might do something like
>   this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['something'])){
    $something = FALSE; 
} else {
    $something = $_GET['something']; 
}
```

> With CodeIgniter's built in functions you can 
>   simply do this:

```
$something = $this->input->get('something');
```

Taken from [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html).

Answer (score 4):

use [Input::get()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html):

```
echo $this->input->get('your_field');
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason that you would be able to use `$this->input->get()` and not `$_GET`.

You may be running an older version (less than 2.0.1) that does not have real $_GET "support". Old versions intentionally unset the $_GET array, assuming because it made things "difficult" for the developers. There is a query strings setting in version 1.7.2 that is very confusing and does not do what you'd expect. Newer versions support $_GET as expected.

Please see here for more information if this is the case:

[CodeIgniter Enabling Query Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729924/codeigniter-enabling-query-strings/5730159#5730159)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must enable 'enable_query_strings = true' first