# Url problem in Rest Api and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I have a rest api call in codeigniter which reads the xml contents from the given url. when i am passing the url with query strings my query strings gets trimmed.

If i print the url before the get method makes a request the url is fine but after it makes request when see the requested url using firebug it does not show the full url with all the query strings.

`$config['enable_query_strings']` has been set to true in the codeigniter.

any help on the above would do great for me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that would help, but did you try changing $config['uri_protocol'] in config.php? 'AUTO' doesn't work for me so I tried 'PATH_INFO' and then it worked. Perhaps try all the possible values to see if one of them works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`$config['enable_query_strings']` is quite different from normal query strings, you want to make sure you're on the latest version of CI and enable `$config['allow_get_array']`

Related post: [CodeIgniter Enabling Query Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729924/codeigniter-enabling-query-strings/5730159#5730159)

As Laurent said, it is a good idea to play with the `$config['uri_protocol']` to get it to work properly. I had to change mine to `PATH_INFO` to get it to work.