# Allow URL parameters in CodeIgniter 1.7.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter version 1.7.2. I need to allow url parameters, for example

```
http://www.mydomain.com/?test=test.
```

I try to change `uri_protocol` from

```
   $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"
```

to

```
   $config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO"
```

and it worked but then all my other links like

```
http://www.mydomain.com/test  does not work.
```

What is solution here?

I also tried to use 
    `permitted_uri_chars`

but I can't made it work.

Comment: I was also forced to work on an old CI install and needed querystring support. This is what helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10283196/844726

Comment: did you use routes.php ? also you should report errors you see when it doesn't works, try enabling logs, then be sure you have a default controller defined in your config.php

Answer (score 0):

The above link from swatkins answers your question but I would have a serious think about using this approach, it's messy, search engines are not big fans and it opens up security vulnerabilities and I really can't think of any good reason to do it.

You can use a get request with a standard URI and pass your parameters via that, using this approach will encourage you to process and check input properly.