# $_GET contains URL string, and the actual query params are emptied -- Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, get, superglobals

I have been working on a web app that has been previously built/worked on by people I have no way of contacting.

I believe we are currently on CI_VERSION 1.7.0.

I've made sure that enable_query / allow_get_array config vars are all true. 
I can see the correct values in the header(query string parameters).

Example of the problem below:

```
//E.g.
//URL: http://www.fakeURL.com/something/stuff?color=blue&gender=boy

var_dump($_GET);
// array(1) { '/something/stuff' => string(0) "" }
```

Comment: Maybe the `$_GET` variable is overwritten at another place?

Comment: @GuyT I think you are right and that is what I've thought, but still I have searched the codebase and cannot seem to find such a thing happening.

Comment: It should work.Are you sure `something` is your controller name and `stuff` your method name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this solution, found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2283881/1626354

I will say that this is more of a 'work-around' than a solution, but I can't invest anymore time in this right now.

Thanks everyone for your helpful suggestions.  Hopefully this will be useful to someone else someday too.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting url parameters with build-in class : input.

```
$p = $this->input->get();
var_dump($p);
```

Codeigniter recommand to do it this way. For example, you can't get a parameter twice with this function as it is emptied the second time. So we don't know how they manage parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of CI the `$_GET` array included the requested controller/method after the URL was rewritten (as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5730159/1734864)), the rest of the info in it was stored in the input class and removed (see the [legacy docs](http://lang-lang.org/user_guide/libraries/input.html)).

As the other answer stated, you'll need to use `$this->input->get();` which will contain the original `$_GET` params.

Comment: I have tried the input class a number of times -- but I will investigate what you've said.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Ah ok, it might be worth updating your question with what happens when you `var_dump($this->input->get());`?

Comment: I found a bit of a work-around and posted it as a reply to this.  But to answer your question, that came back as false.